# Cube not coming out as expected using openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

My cube is not coming out as a cube instead it is coming out as show below:

[image]

I can't seem to figure out why it is not rendering as a cube I was wondering if anyone here had any pointers.

My code is as follows:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h> // glfw manages the window
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <math.h>

#define GLSL(version , shader) "#version " #version " core \n" #shader

int main() 
{
        glfwInit();

        // setup glfw
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

        // create window
        GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

        // window complete OpenGL code below ---------------------------------------

        // initialise glew
        glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
        glewInit();

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        GLuint elements[] = {
                0, 1, 2
        };

        // create the shape of triangle 

        GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
        };

        const GLchar* vertexSource = GLSL(150,
                in vec3 position;
                in vec3 color;
                in vec2 texcoord;
                out vec3 Color;
                out vec2 Texcoord;
                uniform mat4 model;
                uniform mat4 view;
                uniform mat4 proj;
                void main()
                {
                        Color = color;
                        Texcoord = texcoord;
                        gl_Position =  proj * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0);
                }
        );

        const GLchar* fragmentSource = GLSL(150,
                in vec3 Color;
                out vec4 outColor;
                void main()
                {
                        outColor = vec4(Color, 1.0);
                }
        );

        GLuint vao;
        glGenVertexArrays(1 ,&vao);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);

        GLuint vbo;
        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        GLuint ebo;
        glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // create our shaders
        GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertexShader);

        GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

        GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");
        glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);


        //GLuint uniColor = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "triangleColor");
        GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
        glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,5 * sizeof(float), 0);

        GLint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
        glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(2 * sizeof(float)));
        auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        GLint uniTrans = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model");
        GLint uniView = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view");

        glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(
                glm::vec3(1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f),
                glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
                glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
        );

        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniView, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
        GLint uniProj = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "proj");
        glm::mat4 proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), 800.0f / 600.0f, 1.0f, 10.0f);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniProj, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(proj));


        while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
        {

                auto t_now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
                float time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<float> >(t_now - t_start).count();

                glUniform3f(colAttrib, (sin(time * 4.0f) + 1.0f) / 2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

                glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
                model = glm::rotate(
                                model,
                                time * glm::radians(180.0f),
                                glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
                                );

                glUniformMatrix4fv(uniTrans, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

                glfwPollEvents();
                glfwSwapBuffers(window);

                if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS) {
                        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
                }
        }

        glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
        glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
        glDeleteShader(vertexShader);

        glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &ebo);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);

        glfwTerminate();

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ In this case I recommend trying to first make a triangle, then a square, then three square making an open prism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `glVertexAttribPointer()` calls imply a data layout that doesn't match what's in `vertices`.

Specify a layout that matches your data (four-component vertices (XYZW) + four-component colors (RGBA)):

```
glVertexAttribPointer
    (
    posAttrib,
    4, // four-component vertices (XYZW)
    GL_FLOAT,
    GL_FALSE,
    8 * sizeof(float), // a new vertex every 8 floats
    0 // first vertex starts zero floats in
    );

glVertexAttribPointer
    (
    colAttrib,
    4, // four-component colors (RGBA)
    GL_FLOAT,
    GL_FALSE,
    8 * sizeof(float), // a new color every 8 floats
    (void*)(4 * sizeof(float)) // first color starts 4 floats in
    );
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much I've been scratching my head over this for hours!

Comment: @BenMoore: And thank *you* for the revision-1 [mcve]!  They are sadly as rare as they are useful!